# Why does emacs add a tab to the current line when I use "expand abbreviation" feature?

Tags: abbrev

Apologies if my question is silly, it's my first day
using abbrev expand.

I have an abbrev set up like this

```
"bm"           3    "bookmarks-acd1fe"
```

When I press bm tab, I end up with

```
bookmarks-acd1fe<tab character here>
```

I didn't want a tab character, why is it inserting tab?  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Simply inserting "bm" should do nothing. Assume a key followed "m"? Which? How did you call "expand abbrev"?

Comment: I pressed tab to call expand abbrev.

Comment: Okay, added respective answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>, `abbrev` expands and then inserts the tab you entered.  If you had hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> instead, it would have entered a space.

Emacs links process of expanding abbreviations to a couple of character-inserts, called self-insert-command. I.e. when abbrev-mode is on and such a character gets inserted, Emacs looks before point for an abbreviation and expands it if found. Characters which trigger `expand-abbrev` are SPACE and TAB. It's also possible to call it interactively: M-x expand-abbrev RET.